# Does MSSQL JDBC utilize server aliases

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, alias, mssql-jdbc, sql-server-native-client

I am preparing for a SQL Server database migration.  I would like to use the [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/new-alias-alias-tab?view=sql-server-ver16) functionality from the SQL Server Native Client, configured with cliconfg.exe, to redirect my client applications to the new server.  I am using this in conjunction with DNS aliases so I can redirect the connection to a new port.  However, my applications use MSSQL JDBC instead of the native client.

Does MSSQL JDBC use the alias settings from the native client?  Is it, by chance, a wrapper over the native client functionality?  Both are provided by Microsoft.  If not, does MSSQL JDBC have an equivalent client-hosted server name redirect functionality?  How is this configured?

I did some preliminary testing with the native client settings and it seems like the JDBC driver does not utilize the alias.  However, the naming schemes are a bit different between the two so I may not have had the names correct.  I am referring to `jdbc:sqlserver://servername:port` compared to `servername,port` in the alias tool.

Comment: JDBC is cross-platform whereas native client (and aliases) are Windows only. I doubt Microsoft would implement a platform-specific feature in their JDBC driver.

Comment: Considering that the native client is defunct now (it doesn't even ship with SQL Server 2022, per [Support Policies for SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/support-policies-for-sql-server-native-client?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16)), looking at tools on an obsolete driver is a little pointless anyway. Microsoft recommends OLEDB or ODBC.

Comment: @Larnu - The settings are not obsolete.  I just tested and the MSOLEDBSQL linked server provider utilizes the Native Client aliases. SSMS and SQL Server utilize these settings. It is not limited to the legacy Native Client driver. I worked with MS Support this year to configure a relatively new replication feature and aliases were a core component of the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/2009) the `mssql-jdbc` team and at this time (Dec 2022) the driver does not support aliases.